# Javascript conflict in Wordpress between Theme and Gallery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been working on a specific justified gallery for more time than I care to admit, but I have finally managed to get the gallery looking how I need and all the javascript working.

I did all my testing in Dreamweaver but when it finally came to moving what I had into my Wordpress website there seems to be a conflict with some of the javascript already on the site and the javascript I need to make my gallery work.

I have included all my custom javascript into the footer as follows:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/Justified-Gallery/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/Justified-Gallery/dist/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js"></script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/Justified-Gallery/dist/css/justifiedGallery.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">

  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.x-nav > li.current-menu-item').removeClass("current-menu-item");
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {       
jQuery('.flip-btn-1').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".front").toggleClass('flip');
            jQuery(".back").toggleClass('flip');
        });
});

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {       
jQuery('.flip-btn-2').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".front2").toggleClass('flip2');
            jQuery(".back2").toggleClass('flip2');
        });
});
</script>

   <script>

    $('#liveDemo').justifiedGallery({
        rowHeight : 190,
        sizeRangeSuffixes: {
            'lt100':'_t', 
            'lt240':'_m', 
            'lt320':'_n', 
            'lt500':'', 
            'lt640':'_z', 
            'lt1024':'_b'
        }
    }).on('jg.complete', function () {
        $(this).find('a').colorbox(colorboxConf);

    });

</script>
```

I have figured out What is causing the conflict is the jquery.min.js It is stoping Revolution Slider from working and also causing a problem with a testimonial slider (it shows all the slides at once), and my fixed nav-bar is no longer fixed.

Is there a way to find out what is causing the conflict?

Website in question is [www.dangoodeofficial.co.uk](http://dangoodeofficial.co.uk/)

Thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include Javascript libraries like `jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js` and `jQuery` in the footer by a link; you need to correctly enqueue Javascript in WordPress in the theme's functions.php file. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

As a result, you have two copies of the main jQuery library being loaded.

The jQuery document ready functions can be added in the header or footer with `<script type="text/javascript">**</script>` tags.

You've got lots of Javascript errors in the console. Use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and the errors.

Comment: looks like this has been developed as a WP plugin, script should be enqueued in the plugin code with jQuery as a dependency, (and should probably use jQuery(".something") for selector, not $(".something")

Comment: @matt.c: Add your comments as a comment to the original question.

Comment: @markratledge Thank you for this... I am something of a newbie to all of this. I followed the link and watch a video on how to do it, but it isn't working. I probably made a mistake somewhere. This is what my child theme function.php looks like now - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tg68oupz/) Code was too long to add to comment section so I just added it to jsfiddle so it can be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the conflict could be the inclusion of the jquery.js file. You don't need to include jquery separately in your plugin. By default, WordPress is shipped with a jquery file and it is available for use off the shelf.

Comment: The odd thing is I could only get the gallery to work when I included the jquery.js in the footer. Without it, it didn't work. Unless I am missing something? I am a bit of newbie to all of this, so I may have missed something obvious. Thank you